# Laravel search facility doesn't give output

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am doing a search facility function that get's a value from a textbox (it does that I have checked) and compares to 'skill' column in 'skills' table. If there is a match either one character or whole word It should output details from 'handymen' table, these tables are linked with 'hasMany' and 'belongsToMany' in models.

However the issue is that I do get output, but it's a lit of all handymen even if I type an empty string into textbox.

Controller:

```
    function search()
    {
        $skills = Skill::all();
        return view('layouts/search',['skills' => $skills]);
    }
    //$searchTerm = request('skill');
function details() {
    $handymen = Handyman::whereHas('skills', function($query) {
        if(!empty($searchTerms)){
            foreach($searchTerms as $skill) {
               $query->where('skill', 'LIKE', '%'. $skill .'%');
            }          
         }
    })->get();
return view('layouts/details', compact('handymen'));
}
```

View-search:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Search Page')

@section('content')
    <h1>Here you can search</h1>
    <form action="{{url('details')}}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div>
            <input type='text'  name='skill' />
        </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submitBtn" value="Search">
    </form>
@endsection
```

View-details-here should be my results:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('title', 'Add Job')
@section('content')
    <h1>Handyman details</h1>
    <ul>
      @foreach ($handymen as $handyman)
    <a href=  "{{url('skilledHandyman/'.$handyman->id)}}">
      {{$handyman->first_name}}</a>

@endforeach
    </ul>
@endsection
```

Comment: why the for each loop?  foreach($searchTerms as $skill)? put this inside function details and uncomment it $searchTerm = $request->input('skill');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does the `$searchTerms` variable get into the details() function?
Did you omit some code?

I'm asuming it is set in the details function somehow, if that is the case, then you don't pass `$searchTerms` to the scope of the whereHas closure.

Try adding it to the `use` part of the closure, like below:

```
function details() {
    // .. somehow get $searchTerms first here.

    $handymen = Handyman::whereHas('skills', function($query) use($searchTerms) {
        if(!empty($searchTerms)){
            foreach($searchTerms as $skill) {
               $query->where('skill', 'LIKE', '%'. $skill .'%');
            }          
         }
    })->get();
}
```

Comment: I have added     $searchTerms=('skill'); skill is a name of textbox. and I get this:   Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: How about you use `$searchTerms = \Request::input('skill');`? Also since the input will most likely be a string and php expects an array, you might want to make an array out of the input value `$searchTerms = array(\Request::input('skill'));` or in case you want to split terms by spaces `$searchTerms = explode(' ', \Request::input('skill'));`